# OAuth2 - How to add a list of clientId/ client secret as a JSON file instead of a single client id / client secret?

Tags: oauth-2.0, token

In order to secure the communications between my services, I created an Authorization server that generates an access token. my application is storing the Client ID and Client Secret and pass those to the Authorization server in exchange for an access token.

The client ID & my client secret are stored in my configure() method:

```
@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws 
Exception {
    clients.inMemory().withClient("xxx").secret("xxx")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials").scopes("resource- 
server-read", "resource-server-write");
}
```

My question is how can I created multiple client ID & client secret in a JSON file instead of a single value?

Comment: Why would you do that? Use case?

Comment: Here is my use case: I have services that intercommunicate. I am using OAuth2 in order to secure this communication. each service have to have his own (client Id / client secret) defined in the application.propoperties. 
This is why I want to create a JSON file containing these values instead of using a single (client ID / client secret) for all my services.